# How to deal with big number of data - periodic table and elements

Tags: javascript, c++

I would like to operate with quite big number of data - with elements and periodic table.
At first let the program return the atomic weight of given element. How would you perfrom that?

By manually creating a table with 118 elements and searching for given element in `tab1[element][]` and then passing the `tab1[][atomic_weight]` by iterating up to 118 times?

Or maybe instead of creating in program table create a file with the data? Languages are C++ and JS (in browser-JS you can't deal with local files, but only with server ones by using e.g. AJAX, yes?).

Later it will have to perform more advanced calculations. Of course databases would be helpful, but without using it?

Comment: For 118 elements, a linear search may prove as efficient as other searches.  The time saved by using other searches may not be significant (such as nanoseconds or milliseconds).  Also 118 items is not a big quantity.

Comment: So you mean that it should iterate? Ok. But e.g. in C++ let's consider a `string tab1[];` , the first [] will be the elements, but the second [] should be an integer/float, how do it suitable way?

Comment: A suitable way is to place all the attributes into one structure.  Instead of having one array for the names and another for the atomic number, place the atomic number and the name into a structure, then have one array of the structures.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Here are your steps to make this happen:

1. Decide the targets you want your application to run on (The web, local machine...)
2. Learn C++ OR Javascript depending on #1 **(Buy a book)**
3. Come back to this question on Stack Overflow
4. Realize this is not a good question for Stack Overflow

**Tips when you get to a point where you can answer your own question:**

Use a single dimension array with Objects you have designed.  This is one reason why Object Oriented Programming is so great.  It can be expanded easily later.

**Why the single dimension array?**

1. 118 Elements is chump change for a computer even if you went through every element.  You have to touch on each one anyways, so why make it more complex than a single dimension array.
2. You KNOW how large the data structure will be, and it won't change
3. You could access elements anywhere on the table in O(1) time based on its atomic number
4. Groups and periods can be deduced by simple math, and therefore also deduced in constant time.

The jist: 
**You aren't fooling me.  You have a long way to go.  Learn to program first.**

Comment: "You KNOW how large the data structure will be, and it won't change" - not necessarily. Ununspetium was discovered in 2010 and not quite confirmed. It's possible there may be more elements in the future :P

Comment: @Steve Don't get smart with me =)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend placing all the element information into a structure.
For example:

```
struct Element_Attributes
{
  const char * symbol;
  unsigned int weight;
};
```

The data structure to contain the elements varies, depending on how you want to access them.

Since there are columns and rows on the Periodic Table of the Elements, a matrix would be appropriate.  There are blank areas in the matrix, so your program would have to handle the {wasted} blank space in the matrix.

Another idea is to have row and column links.  The row links would point to the next element in the row.  The column link would point to the next element in the column.  This would have slower access time than a matrix, but would not have empty slots (links).

Also, don't worry about your program's performance unless somebody (a user) says it is too slow.  Other entities are usually slower than executing loops.  Some of those entities are file I/O and User I/O.

**Edit 1 - Implementation**
There are 33 columns to the table and 7 rows:

```
#define MAX_ROWS 7
#define MAX_COLUMNS 33
Element_Attributes Periodic_Table[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLUMNS];
```

Manually, an element can be created and added to the table:

```
Element_Attributes hydrogen = {"H", 1};
Periodic_Table[0][0] = hydrogen;
```

The table can also be defined statically (when it is declared).  This is left as an exercise for the reader.

Searching:

```
  bool element_found = false;
  for (unsigned int row = 0; row < MAX_ROWS; ++row)
  {
    for (unsigned int column = 0; column < MAX_COLUMNS; ++column)
    {
      const std::string element_symbol = Periodic_Table[row][column].symbol;
      if (element_symbol == "K") // Search for Potassium
      {
        element_found = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (element_found)
    {
       break;
    }
  }
```